# Can secondary addressbook be used?

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

We are in the process of upgrading to Domino 11.0.1 and using HCL's AppDev Pack 1.0.6.  In our cuurnet website (Domino 9.0.1) we use an auxillary Domino addressbook to store our users login information and we do not use or create user's id files (ie: jsmith.id).  If we use OAuth for authentication, do we need to create id files for our current registrants and store them in the IBM_ID_VAULT and can we still use an auxillary addressbook to store and retreive the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Functional IDs" (The ones that act as apps to access databases you give them permission in) will require an ssl certificate.  Those IDs only need to be vaulted if you wish to do crypto or signing operations.

End users granting access to the app ids(functional ids) do not need to be vaulted, as we do not yet support signing/encryption on the user's behalf (yet).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It is well appreciated.